# Include 2 modules with the same methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module

I have a certain `Controller`, which now includes two `Module`s.

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  include ModuleA
  include ModuleB

  def index
    if something?
      a_method # Method from ModuleA
    else
      b_method # Method from ModuleB
    end
  end

end
```

For some reason `ModuleA` and `ModuleB` have the same logic (methods), but methods' implementation are different. So, I need them to be in separate files (modules) to easy refactoring, because I need to change implementation of methods often. Now, I'm using different method names (prefixes) in different modules.

```
module ModuleA
  def a_method
    a_other_method
    ...
  end

  private

  def a_other_method
    ...
  end
end

module ModuleB
  def b_method
    b_other_method
    ...
  end

  private

  def b_other_method
    ...
  end
end
```

If I use the same method names (`method` and `other_method`) in both modules `method` from `ModuleA` runs `other_method` from `ModuleB` and I get an error.

Is it possible to have the same method names in modules? How I need to name them, to make `method` runs `other_method` from the same module, where it is implemented?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Modules uses Nokogiri in theirs implementation, so I get a Nokogiri error, when `method` from `ModuleA` runs `other_method` from `ModuleB`. In each module there are about 10 methods, which are connected with each other. So, error, which I get, is in modules implementation, when methods mix with each other from different modules. When all methods run in one Module, there is no error. So, a certain error message wouldn't help you to answer to my question, it is not because of modules implementation, it is because of methods mix.

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal depending on your Modules' size but what about *not* including them? Something like this:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    module = something? ? ModuleA : ModuleB
    module.method
  end
end
```